# Order of operations when valueOf is called

Tags: javascript, object, event-loop, coercion, value-of

Right now I'm reading through You Don't Know JS Types & Grammar Ch 4 where I came across this example on coercion. https://repl.it/D7w2

```
var i = 2;

Number.prototype.valueOf = function() {
    console.log("called"); //this logs twice
    return i++;
};

var a = new Number( 42 );

if (a == 2 && a == 3) {
    console.log( "Yep, this happened." ); //this is logged
}
```

I don't get why things aren't off by one. Since var i starts out at 2, when it hits a == 2 shouldn't 3 be returned and then shouldn't 4 be returned when a == 3 is run?

Comment: `i++` returns the value before incrementing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because you used post-increment. That returns the **old** value of the variable from before it's incremented.

If you use pre-increment `++i` then it increments the variable and returns the new value.

```js
var i = 2;

Number.prototype.valueOf = function() {
    console.log("called"); //this logs twice
    return ++i;
};

var a = new Number( 42 );

if (a == 2 && a == 3) {
    console.log( "Yep, this happened." ); //this is logged
}
```

Comment: I'm amazed at the number of questions I see on this site about infix operators. I've not kept track, but it seems there are at least a couple a day, if not more. I think I have way more respect now about the people who've taught me programming, because the difference between the two had been explained very well to me. I've never stopped to think about which operator it is and how it works. On the other hand, I think I now also have more appreciation about Crockford's dislike of infix. If people knew how they worked, there would be no problem with using them, yet apparently it causes confusion.

Comment: @vlaz This isn't infix, it's prefix or postfix. `a+b` has an infix operator.

Comment: @vlaz Most of the time `++` is just used for side effect, not value, like in a `for(i = 0; i < length; i++)` loop, in which case the difference is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

a++ is postfix, it returns the value and then increments.